# Linking Macros to Onedrive

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to save file macro to my teams one drive. This is a shift report with multiple users that I want to put a "save a copy" button on so when we hit save it creates a pdf in a folder on our drive that  is Timestamped with Date, Shift, and Supervisor. Below is what I've been able to get from a tutorial website. I have the URL for the share drive folder I want these to end up in. I need some help figuring out where to plug it in at. Right now when I run the macro it will create a prompt with the file name and where it was saved to. The location looks correct, but when I got to check that location on the SharePoint the file is non existent.
Thanks in advance,
Chris

```
``Sub PDFActiveSheetNoPrompt()
Dim wsA As Worksheet
Dim wbA As Workbook
Dim strName As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strPathFile As String
Dim myFile As Variant
On Error GoTo errHandler

Set wbA = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsA = ActiveSheet

'get active workbook folder, if saved
strPath = wbA.Path
If strPath = "" Then
  strPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
End If
strPath = strPath & "\"

strName = wsA.Range("B1").Value _
          & " - " & wsA.Range("B2").Value _
          & " - " & wsA.Range("B3").Value

'create default name for savng file
strFile = strName & ".pdf"
strPathFile = strPath & strFile

'export to PDF in current folder
    wsA.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=strPathFile, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
    'confirmation message with file info
    MsgBox "PDF file has been created: " _
      & vbCrLf _
      & strPathFile

exitHandler:
    Exit Sub
errHandler`:
    MsgBox "Could not create PDF file"
    Resume exitHandler
End Sub
```

I have tried plugging the URL from https....to the "/" following the last location into the file path in the declaration of "StrPath", and into both "wbA" and "path" on wbA.Path. I'm not sure what else I can change the code to in this macro without causing an error somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to make the target folder available in your One Drive app then use the local path to save the file.